# If I use a C/C++ library in a swift project should memory be ARC managed or manual?

Tags: swift, macos

I am new to swift and I am going to build a project using swift programming language for osx and along with that learn this new language. I need to use an existing backend project which is written in C/C++ if I use this C/C++ project within swift programming should I still have ARC in swift or should there be manual memory management ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use ARC in your swift project without any trouble.  Just keep in mind that everything from the lib will not be managed with ARC (if you create a a struct from the C lib in swift, you will need to clean it up as well).

Comment: Thanks I did not get this part ( if you create a a struct from the C lib in swift) ? you mean if I call a function say swiftfunction() which indirectly called cppfunction() which results in memory allocation in C++ , then I have to clean it up. Is this what you meant ?

Comment: Exactly.  Only Obj-C objects are managed with ARC.  So if your C++ lib calls malloc, you must still call free to release it.